# Typescript - faulty type checking for generic functions returning Promise

Tags: typescript

When a generic fucntion returns `Promise<T>` typescripts type-checking is failing. 
Am I doing somethig wrong, and is there a way to enforce typechecks in such a situation?

```
//Generic function
function get<T>(): Promise<T> ...

//Typed instance of function, should fail at compile-time Because T != T[]
const typedGet: <T = SomeClass>() => Promise<T[]> = get;

//Should also fail, because T != IterableIterator<T>
const typedGet2: <T = SomeClass>() => Promise<IterableIterator<T>> = get;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structural nature of the Typescript type system, and the fact that types are erased at compile time, I don't think it is necessarily faulty.

Let's examine the first case, renaming the type parameter for the signature to make things more clear.

```
const typedGet: <O = SomeClass>(n: O) => Promise<O[]> = get;
```

`get` is generic, and returns a `Promise<T>` and is being assigned to a function that returns `Promise<O[]>`, since there are no other constraints `T` can be `O[]`. Typescript will not try to match the individual type parameters of the function so `O != T` is not a problem.

If we were to add a parameter, the discussion would be different:

```
declare function get<T>(p: T): Promise<T> 
const typedGet: <O = SomeClass>(p: O) => Promise<O[]> = get;
```

Now if we try to match return types, `T` must be `O[]`, but if we match parameter types `T` must be `O` so we can't reconcile this, and we get an error.

Comment: So, if I really want to make the type of promise checked by typescript - I need to add an optional, unused parameter of Type T? This feels like a hack.

Comment: @Anarion not sure what you are trying to achieve, but as far as TS in concerned those signatures are compatible. Is this your full example ? How does `get` depend on `T` since generics are erased `get` will not know at runtime with what `T` it was invoked anyway

Comment: @Anarion If you need the class inside `get` you can pass the constructor as a parameter: `declare function get<T>(p: new() => T): Promise<T> 

class SomeClass {
    private test: string;
}
get(SomeClass);

const typedGetOk: <O = SomeClass>(p: new()=> O) => Promise<O> = get; // this will be ok
const typedGet: <O = SomeClass>(p: new()=> O) => Promise<O[]> = get; // this will fail 
const typedGet2: <T = SomeClass>(p: new()=> T) => Promise<IterableIterator<T>> = get;// this also will fail `

Comment: I'm trying to implement something similar to GenericRepositoryPattern.

I will have a generic implementation, that does all the work, my
`function genericGet<T>(): Promise<T>`
But I don't want to expose it publically - since a user might try to provide a wrong type for T.

Intead, I want to expose typed functions

`getClassA = returns Promise<A>`

So I wanted to know if there is a way to make typescript check that I did not make a mistake, and that my typed function follows the same signature as my generic.

Comment: so what I would like - is to avoid having to pass an argument of the type to typed function. to use it like this: `typedGet('id')` , not `typedGet('id', SomeClass)

Comment: @Anarion ok, but then `typedGet` is not generic

Comment: @Anarion It should be `const typedGet: () => Promise<SomeClass> = get;` And you only have to specify the class once

Comment: htanks, that's exactly what I needed